# Flex CSS Select button with skinClass

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I want to select all buttons with a certain `skinClass`, I've been trying this but it doesn't work:

```
s|Button[skinClass="local.MyButtonSkin"]{
    fontWeight: normal;
}
```

My problem is that I have many buttons with different skins, all of them need to have bold text except one.

How can I select a component by its `skinClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible and either way I would do it the other way around: I'd rather select using a `styleName` and assign the `skinClass` through CSS:

```
<s:Button styleName="myButton"/>
```

CSS

```
s|Button.myButton{
    fontWeight: normal;
    skinClass: ClassReference("local.MyButtonSkin");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this way is much more organized, I've started making some changes and it's looking better overall now